# Select group based on a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to extract customer who has `type=a`:

```
customer type 
A       a       
A       b        
A       c        
B       b       
B       b        
C       c       
C       c
```

My desired result is like this:

```
customer type
A       a
A       b 
A       c
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried the following, but I guess I must add some sentence...

```
df.groupby("customer")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For best performance use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with filtered `customer` by mask in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['customer'].isin(df.loc[df['type'].eq('a'), 'customer'])]
print (df1)
  customer type
0        A    a
1        A    b
2        A    c
```

Or if need use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) test if at least one value is matched by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df['type'].eq('a').groupby(df['customer']).transform('any')]
print (df1)
  customer type
0        A    a
1        A    b
2        A    c
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` Not as efficient as Jez's solution but looks clear

```
df.groupby('customer').filter(lambda x : x['type'].eq('a').any())
Out[56]: 
  customer type
0        A    a
1        A    b
2        A    c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     df1=df[df['customer']=='A']
     print(df1)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sure . I will be careful next time .